# Normalizar base de datos hasta la Tercera Forma Normal

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy diseñando una base de datos para la industria del Cine (ejercicio personal).

- Cada película fue hecha por una compañía.
- Una compañía produce una o más películas.
- Cada película tiene uno o más géneros (acción, terror, etc...)
- Cada película tiene uno o más actores.
- Cada película es dirigida por uno o más directores (es posible que un
  director actúe en una película, incluyendo la que esté dirigiendo).
- Cada película tiene cero o más frases dichas por un actor.
- Cada actor tiene un rol en la película.

Todavía no logro identificar correctamente las `Dependencias Funcionales` y las `Dependencias Transitivas`.

**Tabla Original:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Primera Forma Normal (1FN):**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Segunda Forma Normal (2FN):**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**--EDITADO--**

Llevo esto hasta ahora...

Modelo ER:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Diagrama en SQL Server:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mis preguntas son:

1. Cómo identifico cuáles serían tablas intermedias?.
2. Tratando de seguir las reglas que indiqué arriba, cómo puedo llevar mi esquema a la Tercera Forma Normal?.

Estoy muy confundido, espero puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Podrías subir la foto del esquema de como se relacionan las tablas entre ellas? Todo y así veo que si que te faltan tablas. Género debería ser una tabla que apunta a películas.
A parte crearía una tabla de nombre Atributos_Actores por ejemplo dónde estuviesen los atributos de frase y id apuntando a la tabla Actores.

Comment: Las tablas intermedias se generan cuando una relación es mucho a muchos por ambos lados, ejemplo entre peliculas y director, ya que una pelicula puede tener muchos directores y un director puede dirigir muchas peliculas...

Comment: yo te recomendaria que colocaras  varios datos de pruba y fueras aplicando  las fases normales 1 a la ves  para que pueda ver mas fácil como colocar las tablas con sus atributos te dejo un link con la informacion y un ejemplo https://support.microsoft.com/es-co/help/283878/description-of-the-database-normalization-basics

Comment: @MohamedLbachiri He editado mi post inicial con los avances que tengo desde la 1NF hasta la 2NF. Qúe debo hacer para obtener la 3NF y dónde debo colocar las tablas intermedias? En la 3NF?, estoy medio confuso, espero puedas ayudarme una vez más.

Comment: @estebanfabianpatiño Hola, estaba leyendo ese enlace ayer, pero, no entendí mucho realmente. He editado mi post inicial con mis avances, espero puedas ayudarme una vez más.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que pudiera ser un ejemplo así:

1.- Cada pelicula puede tener varios generos:

`tabla_pelicula` -------> `tabla genero-pelicula` <-------- `tabla genero`

- `genero-pelicula`

  - `id_pelicula`
  - `id_genero`

De esta forma podrás asignarle varios géneros a una misma película, la cual solo se relacionarían mediante los id de película y genero.

**Tienes que pensar en que tabla puede haber vas de un elemento de una misma tabla**

2. Cada película puede tener mas de un actor y mas de un director
   `tabla actor` ----->`tabla película`<--------`tabla director`.

***Aquí si, cada tabla tiene su propio id primario*** y se relacionan en la tabla película.

Es el mismo caso para las frases.

3. Pudieras relacionar al actor con una frase y en que película la dijo:

`tabla actor`---->`tabla frases`<-------`tabla pelicula`

la tabla frases si debiera llevar un `id principal` ya que estarás agregando datos allí a diferencia de la tabla `genero-película` porque esa solo te permitirá estar relacionando una película con su genero.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tratar de ayudarme. Sigo confundido, he editado mi post inicial con los avances que tengo desde la 1NF hasta la 2NF. Qúe debo hacer para obtener la 3NF y dónde debo colocar las tablas intermedias? En la 3NF?, estoy medio confuso, espero puedas ayudarme una vez más.

Comment: He hecho este esquema en SQL Server, captura: http://oi64.tinypic.com/wimr6p.jpg. He aplicado tus consejos, lo he hecho bien?. Basta con aplicarles Foreign Keys o debo configurar algo más en SQL como cascade, etc.. ? Éste sería mi esquema en 3NF?, muchas dudas, espero puedas ayudarme, te lo agradezco mucho.

Comment: @RobertGomez deberías subir todo lo que pueda ser relevante para que tu respuesta sea contestada de forma correcta, crea el modelo en EER y añadelo  para ver la estructura.

Comment: Ten en cuenta lo siguente **ON DELETE CASCADE**
*Especifica que si se intenta eliminar una fila con una clave a la que hacen referencia claves externas de filas existentes en otras tablas, todas las filas que contienen dichas claves externas también se eliminan.*     Es decir todas las filas que tengan una referencia con las llaves que se van eliminar se verán afectadas.

Comment: Hola, tienes razón, he editado mi post inicial con el modelo ER y el diagrama en sql server.

Comment: Pues a mi parecer, esta bien. Tu base de datos esta un poco mas normalizada.

Comment: Tengo duda con tu consejo sobre "tabla actor -->tabla película<--tabla director". Con este modelo no podría asignarle 1 o más actores a una película y tampoco 1 o más directores, tendría que hacer 2 tablas más a parte, cierto?. o no?. Otra cosa, el diagrama en SQL parece bien, pero, como paso eso a modelos ER para indicar mi database en 3NF?, solo debo indicar las tablas que he hecho en SQL (son 10 en total), nada más?.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68511/discussion-between-robert-gomez-and-ferny-cortez).

Comment: Exacto, si tu quieres que una película tienes que crear una tabla que te permita agregar mas actores a la película y es el mismo caso para los actores, SQL tiene la función de crear un modelo EER automático, no se si eso es a lo que te refieres?

Comment: Hola amigo, me ha surgido otra duda respecto a la relación que tengo entre actor --> frases <-- pelicula. Recuerda que cada película tiene 1 o más frases dichas por el actor, creo que el diagrama que tengo para FRASES no es correcto (puedes ver la foto en mi post inicial). No podría hacer bien las relaciones. No necesitaría una tabla llamada ACTORES_FRASES_PELICULAS que tenga id_frase, id_actor, id_pelicula?, de esta forma 1 actor puede tener muchas frases en 1 o más películas?, estoy correcto o no?.

Comment: De hecho si, en una parte de arriba explicaba eso, creo que sí hiciste tú tabla así, deja reviso. Eso de las frases lo había puesto más arriba, en la respuesta **3.** Puse eso, tienes que tener una tabla para las frases donde la relaciones con la tabla actor y la tabla película, los campos que lleva son `id_frase, id_actor,id_pelicula y frase`, no de cuál pudiera ser la duda, vuelvo a comentar que arriba te había comentado esa situación.

Comment: Hola, a ver si me explico de otra forma, por qué la tabla FRASES debe llevar id_frase?, o sea, las frases no son predeterminadas, 1 actor puede tener muchas frases en 1 pelicula o más peliculas. Las frases se digitarán en el programa manualmente. La tabla FRASES debería tener solamente id_actor, id_pelicula, frase, no se si estoy equivocado, es lo único que me falta por confirmar.

Comment: Estas en lo correcto, no es necesaria